# Producing MapServer mapscript map inset?

Tags: mapserver, geodjango

How do I produce a map similar to the one in http://www.nexusenergy.com.au/6468050/nexus-energy-oil-gas-exploration-and-productio.htm using geodjango to drive mapserver?

I would like to dynamically create the insets, based on user supplied input.